# Probability mass function of sum of i.i.d categorical variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the probability mass function of the sum of $n$ i.i.d categorical variables, $X_i$, each taking values $0,1,2$ with probability $(1-p)^2, 2p(1-p), p^2$, respectively?

Comment: Hint:  Your $X_i$ have the same distribution as a binomial random variable with parameters $(2,p)$, and the sum of independent binomial $(n_i,p)$ random variables is a binomial random variable with parameters $(\sum n_i, p)$

Comment: Like @Dilip said, or, for a zero-cleverness solution, use [probability generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).